# Is there any data about the significance of a blood serotonine level test and links to depression or other psychiatric diseases, or simply mood?

Tags: blood-tests, neurology, depression, psychologist-psychology, ssri-selective-serotonin

What does low or high blood serotonine levels tell us. Is there any data on the link between certain conditions and serum serotonine concentration?